# Ask ex-employee / colleague for data removal that relates to company

Tags: employment, data-ownership, employer

I am not sure if this is off-topic but I would like to send a kind of formal email to one of my ex-colleagues to ask for data removal that relates to the company I am in still.

I remember that I received a similar email when I was an employee within a company. On my last day I received some kind of mail that asked me to remove all data related to the company, including passwords, repositories etc. I had to answer with yes / no.

Do you guys have any example for this? Or is this a none common approach?

Comment: Typically passwords are not "removed". If it is a password to a personal account the account is deactivated, if it is a shared password a new password is set (why risk the leaving employee not complying with your request?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the company, what your position was in that company and what information did you have access to while working there.

Basically the company have all the rights to the information and if you would share that information with anyone who does not work there, this includes even your close family members, then in most jurisdictions they would be able to sue you for that.

So in areas that there are sensitive information available, that is very common practice.

Comment: @Smart4555 It is basically that the company existed out of 3. I made a project with my license (github license) but they have made some pull requests in the past. Basically I would like to send them some kind of email that states that they have to remove all data related to that repo. Can you help me furhter with this?

Comment: @KevinVugts What was the license? Who has the copyright to the repo, you or the company? Also, if you want me to help you write that letter, then you're out of luck. There's no "standard" form for such letter. I would suggest you find that letter that was sent to you by the last company you worked for and adjust the context as appropriate. Or ask your direct manager or boss for directions. I think the latter would be safest.

Comment: Currently it is under UNLICENSED. I have the copyright of the repo, since I am the owner of the repo. The letter is in the my closed company mail account, cannot reach it anymore. I am asking for some kind of inspiration / examples on the net, since I am not able to find it.

Comment: If you simply want "inspiration" then look up some NDA samples. Most probably you should have signed something like that with them before they got access to any confidential information to begin with.

Comment: We haven't signed anything together. So that would be out of scope, right

Comment: You can still write a **polite** letter, asking but not demanding, because if they would use any of your copyrighted material without your permission, you could still sue them. Next time sign NDA with them first though. ;)